# Resharper Reorder Type Members with Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, formatting, resharper

I created a simple custom Type Reorder Xml Template.

It works very well, apart from View Models with Dependency Properties or CSLA Objects.

for example i want the ViewModel to look like this:

```
public class ViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    #region Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Property1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Property1", typeof (string), typeof (ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the property1.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The property1.
    /// </value>
    public string Property1
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(Property1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Property1Property, value); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

But after the Reordering it looks like this:

```
public class ViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    #region Constants

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Property1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Property1", typeof (string), typeof (ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the property1.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The property1.
    /// </value>
    public string Property1
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(Property1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Property1Property, value); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Is there a way to keep the DependencyProperty Declaration and the Property together? If Possible i don't want use Tools other than Resharper.